# How can I transform a vue.js project to single html file / single js file

Tags: vue.js

I am looking forward to transform a vue.js project into a single html file / single js file, because the platform I am using this in only accept it this way. Something like this,

HTML:

```
    <html>
<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900|Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@5.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <v-app id="blabla">
      --- code ---
  </v-app>  
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
  <script src="libraries/axios.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
const NewApp = new Vue({
    el: "#blabla",

    vuetify: new Vuetify(),

    data: {
        booolefasdsa: false,
    },

    methods: {}
});
```

My project also has vue router that need to be converted, is there anyway to do this?

Comment: if the actual project uses vue cli you could build it and serve the `dist` folder which contains the project built to be serves via nodejs or any other runtime

Comment: Depends on what you really want to do. Maybe you can have a look at these: https://vue-community.org/guide/ecosystem/static-site-generators.html#summary-tldr